# Polymorphic model and has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a `polymorphic` model `Document` and multiple models with documents linked. One of which the `CustomerPlan` model that `has_many documents, as: :linkable`. This works fine.

In addition I have a `Company` model that `has_many :customer_plans`. As such an instance of Company should also have many documents. How do I properly set up the has_many relation between the `Company` model and the `Document` model?

Currently:

Schema:

```
  create_table "documents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.json     "links"
    t.integer  "linkable_id"
    t.string   "linkable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "documents", ["linkable_type", "linkable_id"], name: "index_documents_on_linkable_type_and_linkable_id", using: :btree
```

Models:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

  mount_uploaders :links, DocUploader
end



class CustomerPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :documents, as: :linkable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_plans
  has_many :documents
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question,

if `Company` `has_many :customer_plans` and `CustomerPlan` `has_many :documents`, then you could have `Company` `has_many :documents, through: :customer_plans`

Comment: Company can also have documents through other models (hence the polymorphism) should you specify a has_many association seperately for each?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to do something like:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_plans
  has_many :documents, through: :customer_plans
end
```

**UPDATE**

based on the new information of company having other documents through other associations, I'd probably go about it this way:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_plans
  has_many :customer_plan_documents, through: :customer_plans, source: :documents
  # you can later do other document associations here
end
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: Company can also have documents through other models (hence the polymorphism) should you specify a has_many association seperately for each?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect an approach I'd probably follow to achieve that